# C refusing to print debug info to console. Why?

Tags: c, loops, debugging, do-while

My C code only prints the `printf` statement if I get rid of my loop. I have tried using regular while loops instead of a dowhile loop but it doesn't work. Anyone know?

```c
/**
 * Src for Planet Miner: Endless Space
*/

const char version[] = "a0.1_0";

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    printf("Starting game... version %s", version);

    int gameRunning = 1;

    do {
        //printf("O"); debugging is fun!
    }
    while (gameRunning == 1); // Main game loop

    return 0; // End program after main loop
}
```

Would anyone kindly help?

I have tried using regular while loops instead of a do-while loop. However, it didn't want to print it out to the console.

Comment: Since you're new I'll mention that you should always compile with `-fsanitize=undefined,address` (I may have spelled it wrong). It catches many bugs. This is more of a preference but I never ever use a do while loop. Most of my loops are `while (1)` too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`printf("0"); fflush(stdout);` will solve your problem.

Comment: Can I have an example? Print "hello world" with this method. Sorry I am fairly new to C

Comment: @TPGlitch: All you have to do is to add `fflush(stdout);` after the line `printf("O");`. That should work in your existing code. No further example should be necessary.

Answer (score 3):

The standard output stream [`stdout`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/std_streams), which is used by `printf`, is buffered by default. If that stream is being directed to a terminal/console, it is usually line-buffered, otherwise it is fully buffered. Whether `stdout` is line-buffered or fully buffered may also depend on which platform you are using.

When `stdout` is buffered and you execute a `printf` statement that does not contain a newline character, you will usually not see the output immediately. You will only see it when the output buffer gets flushed.

Therefore, if you want to see the output immediately, you can either

1. flush the output buffer explicitly, using `fflush( stdout );`, or
2. if `stdout` is line-buffered, you can add a newline character to the output, which will cause the output buffer to be implicitly flushed.

The first option is probably better, because it is guaranteed to work also in situations in which `stdout` is not line-buffered, but fully buffered.

Answer (score 2):

You need a `\n` at the end of the string. There's no println unfortunately